# Does image segmentation algorithm consider only shape? Or size, color and surface pattern as well?

Tags: image-segmentation, yolo, faster-rcnn

I have 100 different object categories that are sometimes closely similar in shape but they differ in color, size and surface pattern. Does any image segmentation algorithm consider color, size and pattern as well or they just look at the outlines of the object?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Image segmentation can be based on the following:

- contrast
- colour
- shape
- pattern
- depth (or temperature, etc)
- motion

Just to avoid citing wikipedia here is a combination of depth and colour segmentation:

[image]

[Complete example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFZS-r_txCI).

Complex colour:
[image]

[Complete example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jidWZZDX39E)

More [segmentation examples](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLsVHuYpywKFNAHKFfImIVg/videos)